# How to write a file to the Response for Internet Explorer Mobile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to write a file to the response for download. I use:

```
      Response.Clear();
      Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + name);
      Response.ContentType = GetMimeType(path);
      Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(path).ToArray());
      Response.End();
```

This works fine on multiple desktop browsers. However, on Internet Explorer Mobile 10 on Windows Phone 8 devices, it fails. As expected, I get a screen with the message "Tap to open".

However, when I tap the message, it navigates to a blank page with the url "Default[x].htm".  "x" has been 1, 2, and 3 so far. If I add the page to my favorites, I can see the full URL of Default[x].html is "file://C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\INTERNETEXPLORER\INetCache\WNW0K564\Default[x].htm".

This is the same no matter what the extension of the file or the MIME Type is. I am stumped as to why this is happening. Is there an alternative method to write files to the response that is compatible with IE Mobile?

As I said, this fails regardless of the file extension or MIME type. For one example, I verified the situation was:

```
filename: themes.ppt, MIME Type: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
```

All the files download fine if linked to directly, but I cannot to do this for security reasons. I would prefer not to make a temporary copy of the files and link to those copies, but I will have to do so if I can't find a way to write them to the response.

Comment: How large is the File, what IIS Version are you using and are you in debug mode?

Comment: The files are anywhere from 0.1MB to 5MB. I am using IIS 7, and I am not in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was causing this issue. To get to the page in which I was writing files to the client, I used

```
Response.Redirect("downloadfile.aspx?" + ...);
```

For some reason, this was causing the issue on Windows Phone devices. I changed it so that the page change is done on the client side. This fixed the issue. You could probably use javascript to do this:

```
location.href = "downloadfile.aspx?" + ...;
```

But I ended up just using a links to directly link to my download page (downloadfile.aspx)

Comment: Anyone have any ideas as to why my solution fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

This solved the Problem on an IIS 8 with .NET 4.5 in combination with WP 8:

It worked in debug mode, but not with debug="false". The Page did not take 90 seconds to execute, but I had to manually set the ScriptTimeout:

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 120;
```

or in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

the default value in non debug mode is 90 seconds.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to work for me. I would upgrade to IIS 8 and .NET 4.5, but I do not have a dedicated server and my hosting provider GoDaddy has not made IIS 8 or .NET 4.5 available.